# Update changes in website made using firebase after site is already deployed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have created a website using react and firebase and hoisted on firebase. After making changes I want them to be visible on my website. What is the process for the same so that the website is not deployed on a different link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you deployed the web site to Firebase Hosting by running some variant of:

```
firebase deploy
```

To update it you can simply run the same command again.